# Compute difference for each combination of dates for a given level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe such as below:

```py
example_df = pd.DataFrame({"group_id": ["12356", "12356", "12359", "12356", "12359"], "date": ["2021-12-03", "2021-12-05", "2021-05-06", "2021-11-04", "2021-06-05"]})
```

I need to find the difference of dates in `date` column for each group id. For example for `group_id=12356` there are 3 dates available

```
["2021-12-03", "2021-12-05", "2021-11-04"]
```

I need the difference between these days in days. There are 3 combinations with these given dates. I wrote a code that does not work the way I want and is very slow because I am using `iterrows`. Is there a shorter and easier way to achieve this?

My code:

```py
%%time
date_diff_dict = {}
for index, row in example_df.iterrows():
    group_id = row.group_id
    group_id_df = example_df[example_df.group_id == group_id]
    date_diff_list = []
    for idx, rw in group_id_df.iterrows():
        if (row.order_id != rw.order_id) & (row.order_id >= rw.order_id):
            date_diff = np.abs((row.date - rw.date).days)
            print(row.date, rw.date)
            print(date_diff)
            date_diff_list.append(date_diff)
            print(date_diff_list)
    date_diff_dict[str(group_id)] = date_diff_list
```

This code gives partially correct answer but misses a day.

Expected output is :

```py
{'12356': [2, 29, 31], '12359': [30]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

(i) convert "date" from string literals to datetime object

(ii) `groupby` "date"

(iii) for each group, use `itertools.combinations` to find pairs of dates

(iv) find the absolute difference in days between the pairs of dates

```
from itertools import combinations
example_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(example_df['date'])
out = example_df.groupby('group_id')['date'].apply(lambda date: [abs((y-x).days) for x,y in combinations(date, 2)]).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'12356': [2, 29, 31], '12359': [30]}
```